# error when add HTML path in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have this error:

"No visible @interface for 'NSBundle declares the selector'pathforresource: of type" .

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

@synthesize WebView1;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResoursce:@"www/index" ofType:@"html"] ;
    NSURLRequest *localRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:
                                  [NSURL fileURLWithPath:localFilePath]] ;

    [WebView1 loadRequest:localRequest] ;

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController.h"
@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *WebView1;

@end
```

Comment: have you imported foundation?

Comment: what do y mean imported foundation ?

Comment: "#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>"

Comment: So version #1 of your question did not show your actual code? That makes finding the typo a bit difficult :-) - And you should also always copy/paste the *exact* error message!

Comment: If that error message is copy and pasted your method name is wrong but in the code it's right. If the code is copy and pasted probably the error message is wrong ... Confusing :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the name of the function because you misspelled:

```
NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResoursce:@"www/index" ofType:@"html"] ;
```

should be :

```
NSString *localFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"www/index" ofType:@"html"] ;
```

And then check the name of the html file . It might be `index.html`.

If you have difficulties in finding the problem you said `pathForResoursce:` instead of `pathForResource:`

Comment: i didnot find any changes what the different between your tow code

Comment: @nemoz: you should invest in some glasses ;) hint: resource

Comment: Resoursce changed to Resource